# Necessity of redirection page in PKCE code flow (IdentityServer4)

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization, identityserver4, pkce

Working on project using PKCE code flow with IdentityServer4. I found this peace of code in IS4 examples:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model, string button)
{
    // check if we are in the context of an authorization request
    var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(model.ReturnUrl);

    // the user clicked the "cancel" button
    if (button != "login")
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            // if the user cancels, send a result back into IdentityServer as if they 
            // denied the consent (even if this client does not require consent).
            // this will send back an access denied OIDC error response to the client.
            await _interaction.GrantConsentAsync(context, ConsentResponse.Denied);

            // we can trust model.ReturnUrl since GetAuthorizationContextAsync returned non-null
            if (await _clientStore.IsPkceClientAsync(context.ClientId))
            {
                // if the client is PKCE then we assume it's native, so this change in how to
                // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
                return View("Redirect", new RedirectViewModel { RedirectUrl = model.ReturnUrl });
            }

            return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            // since we don't have a valid context, then we just go back to the home page
            return Redirect("~/");
        }
    }
```

So the question is why should we show redirect page and how can it improve UX? The only content on Redirec view is message "You are now being returned to the application". Could you give me any reasons to do that or any cases it's necessary for? Thank you!

Comment: It's not that only a message is shown. Please note the refresh meta and signin-redirect.js script.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly useful for native clients with custom redirect URIs.. feel free to remove the code if you don't need that.

Comment: Hi, I've come across this exact same question upon examining the implementation of our login mechanism that uses IdentityServer4.  Could you elaborate a little on this answer?  What difference does a custom redirect URI make here?  Is the "improved UX" basically the difference between displaying a "you are now being redirected" page to the user, rather than the 302 causing a blank page while waiting for the redirect, or is there something more?